# Libsass @include font-face

Tags: include, zurb-foundation, font-face, compass-sass

I'm converting an existing website to use Zurb Foundation 5, and using Libsass rather than Compass to compile CSS from SASS

Having been impressed by the speed of Libsass (and 'grunt') over Compass (and 'watch'), I now have a problem: if I was using Compass, I could access the mixin library with

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

then use something like this

```
@include font-face...
```

Does anyone know the equivalent for a Foundation 5 project created using Libsass?

Comment: how about http://bourbon.io/? I don't have any experience with libsass, so I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Thank you - I've been looking at Bourbon ...and then realised that I can use *@include font-face* with Libsass as it stands! It was the trying to import the compass mixins that was the problem...